# Postgresql: Filter function output vs passing filter parameter to the function

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

Is there a difference in performance between the following queries?

**1. foo() returns an unfiltered set which is then filtered:**

```
create function foo() returns setof table1 as 
$$
   select * from table1
$$ language SQL;

select * from foo() where name = 'bar'
```

**2. foo() accepts a parameter and returns a filtered set:**

```
create function foo(varchar) returns setof table1 as 
$$
   select * from table1 where name = $1
$$ language SQL;

select * from foo('bar')
```

I assume the DB is smart enough to "inline" the function before planning the final query, so that it make no difference in execution. But i'm not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a [wiki](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Inlining_of_SQL_functions) page that answers this.

There are multiple conditions that have to be met for the function to be inlined and thus get opmimized as part of the whole query.

A function in question will be inlined if it's declared `Immutable` or `Stable`:

```
create function foo() returns setof table1 as 
$$
   select * from table1
$$ language SQL stable;
```

`Stable` is more appropriate because the function does a table lookup.

Comment: `explain analyze` on select does show the difference between `stable` and the default.

Answer (score 1):

1. the first runs function without any parameters (possibly getting more data) and then filter data on field. So probably will cost more.
2. the second runs function with parameter (possibly reducing data on function run)
3. without body of the function, it is pure speculation

Comment: added the function body for you

Comment: with your body function will not work  - you need `case when` I believe

Comment: I forgot to add 'returns' statement, but it does work.

Comment: It is in "working condition" enough for someone who has a clue.

Answer (score 0):

Put several million (for example 5) rows   into table, try to use at least 10-20 different values for column `name` (including `'bar'`). Then add index `create index iixx on table1(name)`

Then run `select count(*) from foo() where name = 'bar'`

then try second version  `select count(*) from foo1('bar')`

and you will see difference